# Empty PUT request returning internal server error

Tags: c#, curl, request, put

I am attempting to send a `PUT` request to a URI defined by the documentation of an API. This documentation states you only need to send a PUT request to the URL to reactivate an account.

However, when I send a `PUT` request to this URL with appropriate authentication I receive a `411 length required` response. After reading around I found that this can be bypassed by setting the content-length of my `PUT` request to 0, which works in bypassing the `411` and DOES successfully reactivate the account, however I now receive a `500` internal server error response.

The documentation (and the technical support staff) state the PUT request is to be empty, but with content-length 0. The staff have also been unable to reproduce my issue, but as they do not support C# for the API anymore I assume they are just sending `cURL` requests / using PHP or similar which is not an option for me.

Within C# I have tried with `WebClient`, `HTTPWebRequest` and even Raw sockets to attempt to get this working fully (I need the response code for verification within my code) but to no avail.

The API does not support C# so I'm sailing blind, does anyone know of a way to perhaps replicate an empty entity PUT `cURL` to a url within C# or know of any other potential workaround?

Edit: Examples of code tried:
HttpWebRequest tried, returns 500 server error.
Remove Content-length header to produce 411

```
try
{
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
   request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeB64);
   request.Method = "PUT";
   request.ContentType = "text/XML";
   request.ContentLength = 0;
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

WebClient method (quickly typed out, might be a little wrong I've now scrapped this code so this is just an idea of what it was, it worked but also returned server error (500)

```
try
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeB64);
    wc.UploadString(uri, "PUT", "");
    String status = wc.ResponseHeaders.Get("Status");
}
```

Inspected outgoing and incoming requests with Fiddler, also attempted to compose the request within Fiddler, same issue either method, needing content length or server error, so I am beginning to think that the server I am contacted itself is the issue, not me.

Be aware these requests DID reactivate the subscription despite the 500 error code

Fiddler raw request:

```
PUT https://xxxxxx.recurly.com/v2/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/reactivate HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Y2U0OWZlZGNjMGU3NDEXuIOSmNNYxSakYTU4MzBhZDE0YmU=
Host: xxxxx.recurly.com
Content-Length: 0
```

Response raw:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: blackhole
Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2013 10:38:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2482
Connection: close
X-Request-Id: 69192eb570323c495bb605b432e424fb
```

Comment: As far as I know, a webclient does not do requests any different then a curl request.

Comment: What does your code look like? Have you monitored the call on HTTP-level (using Fiddler or similar) so check what is _actually sent_?

Comment: Edited: added code to show something like what I've tried, I have put breaks in and looked at the actual request sent from VS, all the things I have tried have managed to reactivate the account, but not return a 200 status code.

Comment: Also, I have now implemented a very horrible piece of code that manages to catch the Webexception (500), run an account check to verify account status and then upon verification treat it as a 200-ok code. It's the best fix I can think of for now.. but will still like to get to the bottom of this!

Comment: Fixed issue, missing user-agent header and wrong contentType,

contentType should have been

`request.Accept = "application/xml"`

and the user-agent should have been

`request.UserAgent = "mylib/1.0"`

Thanks for all your input, I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: @Moedig +1 to you sir. A bit of ranting but it seems poorly coded and even worse documented APIs are the norm. I've just had a similar experience and your post helped. thanks